# Why does use with air or water reduce the maximum temperature of certain high temperature / pressure hoses?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, temperature, compressed-air, fluid

This example is a Parker Hannifin model 426/436 "SAE 100 R1 AT / SAE 100 R16 High Temperature Hose".

Here are the temperature specifications:

[image]

(Full [data sheet](https://www.parker.com/literature/4480-P08%20UK.pdf))

Although there is an asterisk after the water/air notes, I can't actually find any corresponding explanation in the data sheet for that.

I am actually looking into hoses for a compressed air application, so I'd like to understand the reason for this reduction in performance.

Comment: The asterisks cross-reference the list of applications, on the right of the image you posted (e.g. "water-oil emulsion" has the same restriction as water, but "oil" does not.)

Comment: Thanks for looking at the PDF... I thought the * under "Applications" referred to the same nonexistent footnote.